# Keep IIS responsive with long running requests - adjust queue priority/position?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I have a few pages/soap calls on my website, which interact with a lot of other systems remotely to fetch data, process it, make a few synchronous db calls and then send the response back. These calls typically take beyond 10 seconds under load and tend to choke up the requests at the IIS.

Is it possible in such a scenario to selectively kill requests or keep them in wait(push them further down the queue under peak loads)? If yes is it possible to do it not via InetManager(as in write code which accesses the worker processes and sorts the requests in the queue in preferred order or some other way)?

**Update:** Killing a request is anyways out of question(even if it comes down to that), as it is going to recycle the app-pool.

Comment: @pst Thanks for editing the title of this post. Although this is such an old topic I just wanted to give it a new way of thinking, given that I am facing such a problem and thinking of alternative solutions/ alternative ways of thinking. Is it possible to do such a thing at all(sort requests in the queue based on ease of delivery)?